# Codeblocks error undefined reference to curl_global_ in C++

Tags: compiling, c++, curl, code-blocks

I new to the web application of c++ and trying to learn about fetching websites and its contents using curl in c++ . My aim is to create a c++ programe which can parse json data from a website. I am using codeblocks as IDE and I have installed libcurl using this command

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

I have tried this sample cpp code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
curl_global_init( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL );
 CURL * myHandle;
 CURLcode result;
 myHandle = curl_easy_init ( ) ;

 curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.yahoo.com");
 result = curl_easy_perform( myHandle );
 curl_easy_cleanup( myHandle );
 printf("LibCurl rules!\n");

 return 0;
}
```

But its throwing this error

```
/test.cpp:10: undefined reference to `curl_global_init'
/test.cpp:10: undefined reference to `curl_global_init'
/test.cpp:10: undefined reference to `curl_global_init'
/test.cpp:10: undefined reference to `curl_global_init'
/test.cpp:10: undefined reference to `curl_global_init'
```

also how to print the output of the fetched website?

Comment: *nix path delimiters are **forward** slashes, not **backslashes**: `#include <curl/curl.h>`

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/a/27550474/996366 link has the solution